# Login issue for some latest devices

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed one school app which communicates with ERP developed in .net. I am facing issue in some latest devices on which my apk gets installed but app is not allowing user to logged in with student. But if I logged in with same student on another device app allows user to logged in. I am seriously not getting this issue.

[image]

**I am getting error java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to (my static IP) not permitted when I run my app on Pixel_2_XL_API_28 emulator**

Comment: Please provide more details about your issue. Post the errors you are getting and the code that is generating them.

Comment: Are you passing device id? Check it. Also what is error are you getting in response?

Comment: @CosminStaicu .. when i run same app on my Oppo device it does not show any error - user can able to logged in into the app.. need to check some more devices with android pie

Comment: @Piyush - no I am not passing any device id

Comment: @CosminStaicu - now I got java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to static ip not permitted exception when I tried to run app on Pixel_XL_API_28 emulator

Comment: Please update the question with the errors posted in the above comment, as more users will be able to see them and give you an answer.

Comment: @CosminStaicu ok

Comment: How about trying [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/940096)

Comment: @Praveenkumar I tried this - now please let me know can i add "http://static ip" in network-security-config xml file? or need to write like "http://google.com" ?

Comment: Its upto the requirement. you can use either domain name or static IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant place your exact problem although. I had this same issue with devices that are using android pie hope this is your issue as well if you are using http instead of https in the api calls devices running android pie shows this login problem.So my solution for this problem is create a resource directory inside your res folder choose the resource type as xml and inside that folder create an xml resource file and name it as network_security_config insert the following code to that xml resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.example.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://example.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>   
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and insert the following lines to your manifest inside the application tag

```
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: thank you .. will try this..

Comment: still getting same error -  W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to (Static IP)  not permitted

Comment: can i use "http://static ip" in network-security-config file?

Comment: ok happy to hear that this issue occurred due to some security updates from android try to use https instead of http for more secure login

Comment: yes sure.. thank you